# Some programs won't start/install without running as administrator

Tags: windows-10, uac, windows-10-upgrade

After upgrading my Windows 7 Pro to Windows 10 Pro I'm having trouble when trying to install certain programs (e.g. PyCharm, JRE) without right clicking the .exe and selecting "Run as Administrator".
Also, certain programs won't start if I don't run them as an administrator (e.g. Dropbox).
I should mention that my user is an Administrator on my machine, and that this issue occurs on all my machines which were upgraded from Windows 7, but not on my machines on which I performed a fresh install of Windows 10.

Tried to entirely disable UAC (through Windows' registry), this solves the problems above, but then I fail to run Windows Metro apps (such as calc.exe :-) )

Any suggestions?

Comment: Disabling UAC is a terrible idea

Comment: Dropbox (the latest version) doesn't require administrator privileges to run on Windows.

Comment: Are you using the latest versions of all applications?

Comment: Yes, using latest versions of all applications.
Dropbox is just one of the problematic programs, many others fail to run / install without running them as admin

Comment: Try running `sfc /scannow` and if that doesn't help, see if `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` works.

Comment: The former reports "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.", the later reports "No component store corruption detected."

Comment: Can you provide the install log of any of the applications that won't install? (When you don't run them as administrator)

Comment: You are aware that Windows 7 and Windows 10 behave differently when it comes to the default permissions of any process you start as a user right?  Unless you specifically escalate the permissions of a process it will not automatically have administrator permissions.

Comment: @Ramhound this still does not explain why on machines on which Windows 10 is freshly installed I can just double click an installation executable and it will run correctly, and on those upgraded machines the same executable will fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, found the source of the problem.
I found out that the local temp folder (C:\Users[MY_USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Temp) was owned by SYSTEM instead of my username, and it didn't have any READ/WRITE/EXECUTE permissions assigned to my user.
Adding full control permissions to my user solved the problem.