# Certain programs wont start unless run as admin

Tags: windows-7, services

Im on windows 7 and this happened suddenly but apps stopped running unless run as administrator. Some of them are Photoshop, After Effects, Acrobat (all abobe), Office Word, Excel etc.

This is not a duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1015139/some-programs-wont-start-install-without-running-as-administrator) thread. I have tried it and it doesnt work at all. 
I think I messed with some startup services, was messing them up. I tried `sfc/scannow` and all other commands on the other thread and also from Microsoft
Forums.

Comment: You have not supplied enough information to help you.  Word does not require you elevate its permissions by default.  You are going to have to tell us exactly, what modifications you did to your system, so we can determine which of those modifications you need to reverse.  You don't have system corrupt, so running SFC to fix system corruption, does not make sense.

Comment: @Ramhound The instructions to run sfc were https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance-winpc/no-programs-open-unless-run-as-administrator-win10/c4eb659d-a82a-4537-b838-987e59576db7 to the very question. And yes word doesnt require to be elevated nor does photoshop. Thats the issue. They wont open unless ran elevated. Thanks.

Comment: @Ramhound  And I just disabled some startup services the day before this started happening, If this could be the case Ill enable them all and give it a shot.

Comment: The instructions you followed are not applicable to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have commented this but I dont have sufficient privilege to do so.

This happened with me a few years back. I used @HackSlash's method for a workaround but the UAC was still so annoying. I restored my PC back to a previous date and found that an App was putting some *device slowing services* into *sleep* and was causing the problem. So if you are using any software that has features like this I would suggest you to uninstall them and any other software that could disturb startup and services.

Comment: As a matter of fact I **am** using Avast Premium Cleaner.

Comment: Try uninstalling or resetting your pc to the install date.

Comment: Great I found the issue. **Avast premium cleanup** was putting come battery draining services to sleep. I re-enabled all the services and it started working. Got rid of the cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have ran a program with elevated permissions it will remember that in the future to ensure the program runs correctly. This feature is provided by **"Program Compatibility Assistant Service"**. Make sure that service is still running.

These settings can seen in the compatibility tab for the program.

Find an example program that is exhibiting this behavior.

- Right click > Properties
- Select the compatibility tab
- Look for the Admin checkbox:

[image]

Comment: This is an alternative but not a solution because doing so I still am not able to open any `.docx` file directly. I still have to open word (which now opens without running as admin, thanks to you) and then go to open and open the file. Thanks. +1

Comment: What happens when you open a .docx directly?

Comment: It doesn't open up. Just like before (after being bugged). Before using your method I had to open word as admin and then `ctrl + o` the file. Now I just dont have to run as admin, rest everything is the same.

Comment: Check your default programs. Ensure that the default program for .docx is the same executable that you right-click on in my example.

Comment: Ya it definitely is. Just so you know Its not only with Word and docx I cant even open psd files with photoshop, pdfs with Acrobat.